# Cygwin sees a file that windows can't--I want to access this file from python

Tags: python, windows, cygwin

I have a device connected to my USB that creates a logfile called Tpolling.log.
I can see it through Cygwin but I can't see it through Windows (with hidden files set to be always shown). I can't access it from python either.

I want to be able to read it in python but python doesn't find it.

The cygwin path that works is

```
  /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/TDA
```

An ls shows that there's a file called Tpolling.log

```
$ cygpath -w "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/TDA"
C:\Program Files (x86)\TDA
```

However, the following gives an error saying no such file as Tpolling.log. I checked the base path with other files.

```
f= open("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TDA\\TPolling.log",'r')
```

Windows can't see the file Tpolling.log when I run "Dir" in command propmpt.
The file is saved on the USB device in its flash memory, I did not ask cygwin to mount it so I am not sure how cygwin can see it.

How do I access it from python, apart from running the python program from cygwin?

Here's the files permissions from cygwin-

```
    drwx------+ 1 SYSTEM         SYSTEM             0 Jul 23 11:27 .
    drwx------+ 1 Administrators None               0 Jul 23 14:39 ..
    -rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM         SYSTEM        684032 Dec 27  2010 NationalInstruments.UI.Design.dll
    -rw
    -rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM         SYSTEM          1078 Jan  3  2010 TDAT.ico
    -rwx------+ 1 lab    Domain Users 2920041 Aug  6 14:50 TPolling.log
    -rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM         SYSTEM         65536 Dec 27  2010 Winsoft.ComPort.dll
```

Comment: Can you use a Cygwin Python instead of a native Python? That would obviously solve the problem…

Comment: I can't unfortunately, it goes into someone else's code I can't modify.

Comment: Hold on… "The file is saved on the USB device in its flash memory". So your USB device is `C:`? How did you manage that? Is it possible that the USB device is actually, say, `F:`, and for some reason Cygwin has mapped it to `/cygdrive/f` instead of `/cygdrive/c`, so you're just looking at the wrong drive letter in native Windows? Or, alternatively, maybe you've somehow gotten `/cygdrive/c` to be an overlay of F: over C: or something?

Comment: I don't really have an explanation, but I was able to solve my problem by getting command shell behaving like cygwin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Application Compatibility to the rescue.

You can find your log file under C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\TDA\TPolling.log

For example if you navigate to C:\ you might see the following buttons in explorer:

- Organize
- Share with
- Compatibility files   ---> this is your friend, click on it.
- New folder

What happens in the background that Windows Application Compatibility feature basically simulates the environment (e.g. directories, files, registry keys) for some programs, e.g. for Cygwin and the TDA program. These files are there for programs which need compatibility, but other programs like explorer.exe can't see it.

I thought there is some rootkit on my machine, because I saw files from cygwin but not from explorer. At least it turned out these files are not rootkits, kind of :)

Comment: +1 Similar: [File only visible to cygwin, not windows?](http://superuser.com/q/400600)

Comment: Is it possible to disable this behaviour ? (would rather get "access denied" message than this weird shadow world)

Comment: Is there any way to disable this behaviour?

Comment: Compatibility files was removed from windows 8; however, go to %LocalAppData%\VirtualStore you will find your file there

Answer (score 1):

`dir /a:h`   will show "hidden" files.

`dir /a:s`   will show "system" files.

If you want to see the file in Windows Explorer, you can uncheck the "Hide protected operating system files" option in the File View options dialog.

You might want to try "dir /a:s >files.txt", and then examining that file to find out if there are any non-visible characters embedded in that filename, and also to see if you have the rights to read / update that file.  Otherwise you should be able to open it from Python.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't fix it. Here's the file permissions from cygwin, compared to another file i can see...-rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM         SYSTEM          1078 Jan  3  2010 TDAT.ico
-rwx------+ 1 lab1    Domain Users 2920041 Aug  6 14:50 TPolling.log

Comment: @Illusionist  Don't use Cygwin to look at file permissions:  Windows ACLs are finer grained than Unix file permissions.   Make the Windows Explorer fix I suggested, then navigate to the appropriate directory, right click on the file, and look at the "Security" tab.   Check that you (or the process your script runs under) has the right to read and update that file.   Did you check for invisible characters (e.g. an embedded leading space)?

Comment: Dir /a:s doesn't give any output. I'm on windows 7.  Output is - Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 30D5-1CC3

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\TDA

Comment: Curt, I can read the file in Cygwin.  I made the folder changes you suggested but I still don't see the file.

Comment: @Illusionist `dir /a:h` doesn't show anything either?   Can you see the file in Windows Explorer after making the "File View" options change I suggested?

Comment: Curt, nothing from dir /a:h and I can't see the file in windows explorer either. I am pretty sure the file is stored on the USB drive.

Comment: @Illusionist   I'm all out of ideas then:  it sounds possible that the file does not actually exist where Cygwin says it does, but that's pretty bizarre behavior.   When you get this figured out, please post the solution:  I'm dying to know, at this point.

Comment: The file does exist and I don't have an explanation. However, I just realized I can run a copy command from python asking cygwin to copy the file somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if someone has a similar problem- this is how I solved mine. Huge thanks to Curt and abarnert for helping me get here. I made command prompt behave like cygwin  (added cygwin path (c:\cywgin\bin for me) to my path variable ) and then I  could just use os.system() to copy the file over from my python program over.