# Using GCC to compile C code

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

I installed MinGW on my **Windows** 8 laptop and tried to compile a C code file with

```
gcc test.c -o test.exe
```

the compiler gave no warnings or errors but it did not create test.exe

how do i get the compiler to create the file

test.c

[image: test.c]

My terminal session
[image: this is what i tried on terminal]

An interesting observation:

When I deliberately introduce an error in the code and try to compile the compiler shows the error

Code with error
[image]
Compiler output
[image]

When I try compiling the same code using Command Prompt

This is what it shows
[image]

But the file does exist in the MinGW\bin directory
[image]

I moved the

```
test.c
```

file to

```
C:\
```

and started the command prompt in the

```
C:\MinGW\bin
```

directory

and here is what it outputs
[image]

Problem partially solved:

I disabled hybrid boot in windows 8 and restarted the computer. The compiler now works in Command Prompt but not in PowerShell.

Comment: That's how you do it. If there's no errors you should have a `test.exe` file in your current directory.

Comment: compile using -Wall option to display warnings:

gcc -Wall test.c -o test.exe

Comment: Like Joachim said, this should work. There is some piece of information missing here.

Comment: That screen shot appears to be cut off at the bottom.  Are you sure `test.exe` isn't below the text you quoted?

Comment: Maybe it silently died. Check %errorlevel%.

Comment: Maybe powershell spoils arguments

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but in the future when posing code, please post it as text and not as a screenshot or picture.

Comment: You should try to run GCC from Windows Command Prompt.

Comment: The problem from the old Command Prompt window, is that the `PATH` is probably not set up correctly, that's why it can't find the DLL.

Comment: Did you try running it from the native MinGW shell? Not from Windows Power Shell and not from Windoiws Command Prompt, but from the whatever native "shell" application comes with MinGW.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24661377/971127

Comment: @AndreyT I don't think there is something like a native MinGW shell application

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Nothing in my antivirus logs

Comment: @LakshayGarg - untrue, msys is a shell environment for specifically intended to support the MinGW tools.

Comment: @Constantin basically had the answer, but the directory which is missing from the search path is the mingw lib directory - both that and the bin directory are needed.

Answer (score 18):

Try to compile your code normally as

`gcc test.c`

If you get default output file `a.exe`,then go for

`gcc test.c -o test.exe`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you go through this compilation instruction :-

`gcc -o test.exe test.c`

I believe this code runs perfectly on your windows system.Please inform if it doesn't!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I came across this after having this same issue and managed to solve it.

When I installed MinGW on my computer, I didn't add the MinGW bin directory to my PATH (`<mingw install dir>\bin`). I had written some code that referred to the GNU compiler binaries by their full path, and when I tried to compile something I experienced the same behavior you described.

So it seems like MinGW won't work properly unless it is added to your PATH. I think it's weird that gcc didn't complain about it though.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is Microsoft's use of `VirtualStore`.

This can cause problems with "missing" files with Cygwin. See for example, [Cygwin sees a file that windows can't--I want to access this file from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087991/cygwin-sees-a-file-that-windows-cant-i-want-to-access-this-file-from-python) and https://superuser.com/questions/400600/file-only-visible-to-cygwin-not-windows.

To verify whether this is the case, try doing a search of your entire hard drive for the file `test.exe`. Or try MinGW's `ls` rather than `dir`.

And since the OP "partially solved" the problem by moving to another directory, this could be the cause.