# I have installed gcc home brew command line tools on OS Catalina. How to run?

Tags: c, macos, gcc, homebrew, macos-catalina

I have installed version 9.2.0 of gcc from the homebrew package on OS X Catalina 10.15.3

I am trying to run the C11 language on XCode as it is part of my C language coding class. The C99 language doesn't run the functions like rand() that we are using regularly.

After many trying hours, I am still unable to figure out how to actually build code using the C11 editor* on my Xcode IDE. I have a feeling it might have something to do with setting the framework or creating an SDK, but I'm not sure how to do this.

*I may be using the wrong terms here. It might be that I'm actually unable to compile on Xcode and I have to use the terminal? Please feel free to correct the misuse of terms I am completely new to programming and I'd appreciate learning the correct way. Cheers! X*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that Xcode is the best solution for you. It would be easier to invoke the gcc compiler from the Terminal window.

Use

> gcc test.c -o test
>   and to run
>   ./test
>   as the 'app' should be in the current folder (i.e. ./)

Modified from [Using GCC to compile C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819206/using-gcc-to-compile-c-code)